# Restrict page access in wordpress based on the logged in user's email

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to restrict a page on my wordpress website to user's that match the emails I have provided. If some other user or non-logged in users open the page the should receive a message that they do not have permission to view this page. Apart from the allowed users, admin should also be able to view the page. I have searched alot but there is no plugin that provide this functionality, only user role based restrictions are available. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to check users against their user `role` instead of their email addresses.

You can use built-it user roles of Wordpress such as editor or you can create your `customrole` with this code.

Example codes given below should go to your child theme's `functions.php` or you can install **[Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/)** plugin to inject the custom functions to your WP site.

```
// Add custom role
add_role("customrole", __( "Custom Role" ),array('read' => true));
```

You can then assign users that you want to give access to certain pages by changing their roles.

I prefer to use a shortcode to restrict a page to a certain role or roles.
You can use this code to create your custom shortcode. It will redirect users to 404 page who don't have access.

```
// Make a certain page available only to customrole users
function shortcode_restricted_page() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();    
    $current_username = $current_user->user_login;
    $role = $current_user->roles[0];

    if ($role == 'customrole' || $role == 'administrator') {
        // Access granted to the page
        return;      
    }
    else {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
        get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
    }    
}
add_shortcode('restricted_page', 'shortcode_restricted_page');
```

You can now add `[restricted_page]`shotcode to any page's content to restrict that page easily.

Comment: Hello, this works nicely, what if I want to show a message like "you don't have access to this content" if a non authorized user signs in.

Comment: @UsamaQasim you need to modify your page template and check for the user role at the top of the page and replace content for not authorized users.